# Yellow Flymake Tooltip / error box disappearing too early

Tags: haskell, flymake

Are you using Flymake + Emacs + GHC Inferior Mode?   When I have an Flymake Error raised with red background color in the editor - I can move the mouse over and get an yellow tooltip explaining the error. Unfortunatelly the tooltip disapperas approx. 10 seconds later.

How can I prevent this?  My error messages are long and I need time to read :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are really attached to overlays, I find it much more convenient to have the error messages displayed in the echo area. To try out if you like this behavior, you can easily toggle it with `M-x tooltip-mode`. If you are the keyboard centric type, also see the discussions on EmacsWiki on how to display FlyMake errors without having to mouseover them:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake

Comment: It is very convienient, because now I can hide the inferior haskell process log window, while having error messages displayed in the echo area, and then there is more space for pure haskell code :-) Wonderful.

Comment: ooops Now I see, that long error messages are truncated after 7 lines in the echo area....... not few errors in Haskell Programs seem to be very verbose and long... How can I extend the echo area to extend to more then 7 lines??  thank is very aprreciated

Comment: it is not constantly 7 lines, it seems to be a given percentage of the screen height. If I make the screen taller, the amount goes up to 13 lines.... but even then, error messages got truncated

Comment: The error message should also go to the `*Messages*` buffer, how many lines can be customized through the `message-log-max` variable.